# how to get values from api response that start with a variable?

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Recently I have been trying to learn about api's a bit more so sometimes when I come across a new one I like to take a look at it. One that I found recently looks a bit strange to me. I usually see normal json on a lot of apis but this one is a bit different. I am unsure if it is just poor design or if they have a good reason for the responses being the way they are.  Here is an example of what the output was.

Example:

```
var List = {
 'DATA': {
  'RESULT': '1',
  'CONFIG': [{
    'value1': '123',
    'value2': 'example',
    'value3': '456',
    'value4': 'text'
   }
  ],
  'INFO': [{
    "value1": "123",
    "value2": "example",
    "value3": "456",
    "value4": "text",
    "value5": "example2",
    "value6": "789",
    "value7": "text2"
   }, {
    "value1": "123",
    "value2": "example",
    "value3": "456",
    "value4": "text",
    "value5": "example2",
    "value6": "789",
    "value7": "text2"
   }, {
    "value1": "123",
    "value2": "example",
    "value3": "456",
    "value4": "text",
    "value5": "example2",
    "value6": "789",
    "value7": "text2"
   }, {
    "value1": "123",
    "value2": "example",
    "value3": "456",
    "value4": "text",
    "value5": "example2",
    "value6": "789",
    "value7": "text2"
   }, {
    "value1": "123",
    "value2": "example",
    "value3": "456",
    "value4": "text",
    "value5": "example2",
    "value6": "789",
    "value7": "text2"
   }
  ]
 }
};
```

This is generally pretty much what I would normally use to fetch a json response.

```
$url = "http://example.com/endpoint";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Cache-Control: no-cache'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, FALSE);

$json_response = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close ($ch);
$result = json_decode($json_response, true);

foreach ($result as $info) {

}
```

The above would not output anything because it comes out as a string so I tried changing:

```
$json_response = curl_exec($ch);
```

to

```
$json_response = substr(curl_exec($ch), strpos(curl_exec($ch), "{"));
```

and then printed with

```
print_r($json_response);
```

Which gave me the entire response but I want to know how I can actually run it through a loop to get the individual values like I would normally do with normal json.
I have tried combinations of stripping the beginning, converting single quotes to double quotes, turning it into an array using explode and using json_encode and json_decode etc but I can't figure out what to do to be able to run it and get the individual values.

If anyone has any suggestions or examples of how I could achieve this it would be much appreciated. It would be nice to know in case I run across something like this again and actually want to do somethng with it. Thanks.

Comment: can you echo "<pre>";print_r($result) and show output

Comment: I don't remember the site it came from because I just copied and pasted the response the other day to look at later but I ran it with that and my example and I get no response. Nothing prints at all.

Comment: It's not valid json so I believe that is why $result won't print it.